# Hidden fields not displaying right in formpanel

Tags: javascript, forms, layout, extjs, formpanel

I have a formPanel with a column layout. It works perfectly as long as there are visible fields in every column.

I tried adding in hidden fields to provide space for the parts of the column where I need it but it's displaying very strangely. I did try changing to adding in textFields and hiding them but it was not keepingany space at all.

The screenshot below shows what I mean. There is a hidden field at the end of the 1st row at column 3 and at the bottom of the column 1 and 3 but the layout doesn't show that.

The hidden fields have been implemented as (with unique id/name values):

```
{
                    id:'my_field_id',
                    name: 'my_field_name',
                    xtype: 'hidden'                
                    }
```

And my formpanel columns have been configured similar to:

```
id: 'myForm'
     ,title: 'Search Form'
     ,frame:true     
     ,waitMessage: 'Please wait.'          
     ,initComponent: function() {    
         var config = {                 
            items: [{
                layout:'table',
                items:[{
                    //columnWidth:.25,
                    layout: 'form',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: "From Date",                        
                        id: 'date1'
                        },

                        {
                        xtype:'combo',                             
                        id: 'fieldSelecCmb1',                               
                        hiddenName: 'ddi_country',                             
                        anchor:'98%',
                        store: fieldStore,
                        displayField: 'name',
                        valueField: 'alpha2code',
                        selectOnFocus: true,
                        mode: 'local',
                        typeAhead: true,
                        editable: false,
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        value: 'emp_id',
                        listeners:{ 
                            select: { 
                                fn:function(combo, value){                                         
                                    myStore.load({params:{ddi_country: this.value}});
                                      }
                                }  
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            id:'my_field',
                            name: 'my_field',
                            xtype: 'hidden'                
                            }
                    ]
                },
```

[image: form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same problem .. we defined a component

```
Ext.define('NCEN.extended.columnSpacer', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Display',
    alias: 'widget.columnSpacer',
    value: '  '
});
```

and just use it like

```
xtype: 'columnSpacer'
```

Comment: where exactly do you put the ext.define? What layout does this work best with - table or column?

Comment: the define should be after you define your application component, and before you use it, i've made a mistake you can use it like xtype:'coulmnSpacer', but if you don't want to define a new component you can use {xtype: 'displayfield', value: '  '}, i've made that component because i've been used it often. As for the layout i normaly used it in table but i believe it works well with column too

Comment: that's partially worked but the middle textfield in column 3 is still hanging. There's no formatting at all in my formpanel so it should align with the drop downs. See updated screen shot. Any ideas?

Comment: i see you have a lot of spacing between the rows, the empty display field takes about 20 or 22 px in height, but your date fields take about double given the fact that the label is above... so i believe that is the problem ... maybe to the 3 column columnspacer specify the height 42 ... 20px for the label and 22 for the datepicker

Comment: that's sorted it out perfectly. Thanks!